# Passing empty key in startkey array for a view

Tags: javascript, couchdb, cloudant

I have a view returning multiple keys. My only question is: how do I retrieve all the data, if I don't have a specific key ? For example: I want to retrieve data for a specific id, no problem. But when I want all data for all ids, I can't put 'any' or '{}' or anything else. It just won't work. Is there any workaround ?

```html
startkey: [null, queryDate.from],
endkey: [null, queryDate.to, {}],
    
    
// here I put null, but won't work...
```

Comment: FYI http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/api/database/bulk-api.html

Comment: @marekful how does this help me though ? I read already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vector-valued keys you can only wild-card from the end, not the beginning.